# Why must context be retrieved via the get_context_data method of the generic class DetailView?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a simple question which i will explain. I am reading about generic views using the docs on djangoproject.com, On this page they show the following example:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

My question is: Why would `context` need to be initialized by calling the `get_context_data`  method from `super()` when `ArticleDetailView` is already inheriting from `DetailView` ?
Can't you already access the context through the get_context_data of the subclass? Like `self.get_context_data(**kwargs)`?

I'm confused!

EDIT: heres the link to the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: Why would context need to be initialized by calling the `get_context_data` method from `super()` when `ArticleDetailView` is already inheriting from `DetailView`? Can't you already access the context through the `get_context_data` of the subclass? Like `self.get_context_data(**kwargs)`?

If you call `self.get_context_data()` you will make a call to the `get_context_data(..)` method of your `ArticleDetailView`, and thus call exactly the **same *method***. This thus means that you get stuck into **infinite recursion**, until eventually the call stack is exhausted and you obtain a `RecursionError`.

You do not *per se* need to retrieve the context of the `super()` proxy-object, for example if you want to construct a context dictionary "from scratch". But a `DetailView` will normally already inject a lot of data into the view. For example it will add an item `object` to the dictionary that refers to the object about which you want to show data, and `view` that refers to the instance of the view that is processed at that moment.